# Docker on WSL won't bind mount $HOME

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the strangest situation using Docker on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu 16.04). I'm trying to bind mount `/home/username` (or just `$HOME` for convenience) as a volume in a container, and instead of finding the content of my home directory in the container, I get some other volume entirely.

What's stranger is that this 'other volume' persists from one container to the other, whenever I try to bind mount `$HOME` or `/home/username`. If I `touch` a new file, it appears in all other containers I mount `$HOME` into. All other bind mounts to any other directory work correctly.

E.g. these all share the same mystery folder:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/username:/test alpine sh
docker run -it --rm -v $HOME:/test alpine sh
docker run -it --rm -v $HOME:/test -v $HOME:/test2 alpine sh
```

When I do a `docker volume ls` there's no volume called `/home/username`, so that rules out accidentally having a docker-hosted volume with the same name.

What is this mysterious volume I'm mounting, and why is docker not mounting my `$HOME` directory correctly?

Comment: Where is the Docker Daemon you are connecting to located? Which dockerd flavor are you using - Docker For Windows, Docker Toolbox, other?

Comment: Also please post the result of `docker inspect` of your container here, especially the volumes part: `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <containerid>`

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows and pointing WSL to it by setting `$DOCKER_HOST` to `tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`. No problems with this so far.

Results of `docker inspect`:
`[{bind  /home/martaver /test   true rprivate}]`

Comment: The results of `docker inspect` tell us this 'mistery' volume is located on your docker host (the Hyper-V VM) in the `/home/martaver` folder.

Comment: Why would it create a volume there, instead of mounting /home/martaver from WSL? It mounts all other folders correctly. Also, this volume isn't visible on `docker volume ls`...?

Comment: It's not listed because it's a host mount.

Comment: 'Why would it create a volume there, instead of mounting /home/martaver from WSL?' - I could ask an opposite question. The host mounts are done to the folders in the fs of the machine which hosts the dockerd (MobyVM Hyper-V virtual machine in your case). This is the biggest gotcha of Docker For Windows. To mount a local folder (where you are calling the `docker *` CLI commands) to the container you first have to share it with the dockerd machine.

Comment: I'll post an answer explaining this later on

Comment: Thanks! Actually, now that I look at it, NONE of the directories in WSL outside of `/c` or `/d` seem to be able to be mountable to docker. So for docker to be able to mount them, I should somehow make the Hyper-V MobyLinux VM mount root and home...? Or what's the correct solution here?

Comment: Exactly. Docker For Windows has built-in mechanism for sharing drives with the VM. This is why /c and /d work for you. You probably enabled them as Shared Drives in the Docker For Windows configuration GUI (as in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/)). To be honest I don't know how to share other WLM's folders with Docker's VM. In fact I don't know if it's possible at all. Yeah, using Linuxish Docker on Windows is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Answering a question "How do I access my WSL FS from outside WSL" might help you with that.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-ssh-into-the-betas-mobylinuxvm/10991) on how to inspect MobyVM's filesystem. You'll find your `/home/martaver` folder there.

Answer (score 1):

I used the instructions in https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work to set up everything.

Then I had to explicitly `export HOME=/c/Users/rfay` so that the Docker daemon on Windows could access it. But that worked. The basic magic is that your pathing in WSL has to be something that the Docker daemon can translate in native Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the mound point as suggested by @rfay. Rather if you use a little command foo you can use pwd and sed to fix the value for you.

`docker run -it -v $(pwd | sed 's/^\/mnt//'):/var/myfolder -w "/var/myfolder" centos:7`

pwd will return the current working folder, usually in the format '/mnt/c/code/myfolder'. Piping this to sed and replacing '/mnt' with nothing will leave you with a path such as '/c/code/myfolder' which is the desired path for docker for windows. you need to wrap the whole thing in $() to cause it to be executed in place.

I find this works really well.