# Where on the host can I find Docker bind mounts that are expected to be on a network drive?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, wsl-2, network-drive

I'm running Windows 10 with WSL2 and a network drive, `H:`.

When I run a Docker container with bind mounts to a location on the local `C:` drive, everything works as expected: data written to that location in the container appears locally on `C:`, and new files in `C:` appear in the container.

Here, Docker was started using PowerShell with `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Scripts\R_Docker_Testing` as the working directory and the `.\volume_data` directory already existing.

`PS C:\Users\Userame\Documents\Scripts\R_Docker_Testing> docker run -it -v "$(pwd)\volume_data:/home/app/data" test-r bash`

When I switch to a directory on the `H:` drive, `H:\Username\R_Docker_Testing`, the same command executes and works properly, except that there appears to be no communication between the `H:` drive and the container.

`PS H:\Username\R_Docker_Testing> docker run -it -v "$(pwd)\volume_data:/home/app/data" test-r bash`

Files written in the container will persist across containers, but do not appear in `H:\Username\R_Docker_Testing\volume_data`. Similarly, files already existing inside `H:\Username\R_Docker_Testing\volume_data` are not found in the container.

Docker does not appear to be creating a volume:

```
PS H:\> docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
PS H:\>
```

```
PS H:\> docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 264
[{bind  H:\Username\R_Docker_Testing\volume_data /home/app/data   true rprivate}]
```

```
PS H:\> docker inspect <container-id>
.
.
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "H:\\Username\\R_Docker_Testing\\volume_data",
                "Destination": "/home/app/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
.
.
```

My question is: **Where are these files being stored on the host so that they persist across containers?**

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM r-base:latest
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/scripts
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/data
RUN install2.r --error --skipinstalled --ncpu 1 here
COPY .here /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY Simple_script.R ./scripts/
```

This question seems relevant:
[Docker on WSL won't bind mount $HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589077/docker-on-wsl-wont-bind-mount-home)

Comment: did you find the location where the files are stored?

Comment: No, and I've had to stop work on this particular problem. It will probably show up again in the future, so I'm still interested in the answer.